# Killing a background process launched with python sh

Tags: python

I have a compiled program I launch using python sh as a background process.   I want to run it for 20 seconds, then kill it.   I always get an exception I can't catch.  The code looks like

```
        cmd = sh.Command('./rtlogger')
        try:
            p = cmd('config.txt', _bg=True, _out='/dev/null', _err='/dev/null', _timeout=20)
            p.wait()
        except sh.TimeoutException:
            print('caught timeout')
```

I have also tried to use p.kill() and p.terminate() after catching the timeout exception.   I see a stack trace that ends in SignalException_SIGKILL.   I can't seem to catch that. The stack trace references none of my code.  Also, the text comes to the screen even though I'm routing stdout and stderr to /dev/null.

The program seems to run OK.  The logger collects the data but I want eliminate or catch the exception.  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_timeout` for the original invocation only applies when the command is run synchronously, in the foreground. When you run a command asynchronously, in the background, with `_bg=True`, you need to [pass `timeout` to the `wait` call](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/command_class.html#RunningCommand.wait) instead, e.g.:

```
    cmd = sh.Command('./rtlogger')
    try:
        p = cmd('config.txt', _bg=True, _out='/dev/null', _err='/dev/null')
        p.wait(timeout=20)
    except sh.TimeoutException:
        print('caught timeout')
```

Of course, in this case, you're not taking advantage of it being in the background (no work is done between launch and `wait`), so you may as well run it in the foreground and leave the `_timeout` on the invocation:

```
    cmd = sh.Command('./rtlogger')
    try:
        p = cmd('config.txt', _out='/dev/null', _err='/dev/null', _timeout=20)
    except sh.TimeoutException:
        print('caught timeout')
```

You don't need to explicitly kill or terminate the child process; [the `_timeout_signal` argument](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#timeout-signal) is used to signal the child on timeout (defaulting to `signal.SIGKILL`). You can change it to another signal if `SIGKILL` is not what you desire, but you don't need to call `kill`/`terminate` yourself either way; the act of timing out sends the signal for you.

Comment: What I'm seeing doesn't seem to match what you are telling me.   You say no work will be done between launch and wait when I use _bg.  I see that the logger does run and it is shutdown at the timeout.  However, if I don't use the _bg, it never reaches the timeout--it just keeps running.

Also, my original problem is that I always get "Exception in thread background thread for pid xxx".   My question is how to avoid or catch the exception or at least supress the printing of it.

Comment: @user1625344: When I say "no work will be done", I mean your *program* isn't doing anything during that period. The subprocess will launch in the background, but if you immediately `wait` on it, it's no different than running it in the foreground (which is really just doing the `wait` inside the call that creates the process). As for the exception, it's unclear where it's coming from; is that output from `rtlogger`, or your own script? If it's your own script, you might try adding a catch block for `except Exception as e:` and `print`ing `type(e)` to figure out what it's throwing.

Comment: Not running in background like you suggested eliminates most of my problems.  I don't know why my earlier foreground efforts didn't work.